# opencv for c gtk warning cannot open display

Tags: c, opencv, gtk, cygwin

I have scanned other questions with similar headers, but non worked with me.
I am using cygwin on windows 7 with its opencv package using clang compiler for c, When I tried a simple program to view an image it gave me this message
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display

I have tried setting DISPLAY = 0.0 and didn't solve it just added 0.0 
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display :0.0

Comment: You should post what you have tried up to this point so we can find the issue.

Comment: I don't know what I have to do, but I think the problem lies in cvShowImage.

Comment: I tried some solutions, but they were for linux not windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with cvNamedWindow GUI. It has to be opened from x server(x app menu), so just setup cygwin/x.
I didn't open webcam, so I have changed to MinGW and cmake.